GetTokenAsync() method throwing exception "The resource principal named was not found in the tenant"
I'm upgrading the Microsoft library from
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

to
using Azure.Identity;

The existing code was:
 public StringValues? GetHeaderForUri(Uri uri)
 {
     var header = GetToken().GetAwaiter().GetResult().CreateAuthorizationHeader();
     return header;
 }

 public async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetToken()
 {
      AuthenticationContext ctx = 
               ctx = new AuthenticationContext(
               "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"+_options.Tenant + "/");            

      AuthenticationResult result = null;
      ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(_options.ClientId, _options.ClientSecret);
          
      if (ctx != null) 
          result = await ctx.AcquireTokenAsync(_options.ClientId, clientCredential);                      
                   
      return result;
}

The new code equivalent to the above is:
public StringValues? GetHeaderForUri(string resoureURI)
{
    var tokenValue = GetToken(resoureURI).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    // Create the authorization header
    var header = $"Bearer {tokenValue}";

    return new StringValues(header);
}   
    
async Task<string> GetToken(string resoureURI)
{
    var scope = resoureURI+"/.default";
    var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(new[] { scope });        
    
    Azure.Core.AccessToken accessToken;
    var token = string.Empty;
       
    try
    {   
        var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(_options.Tenant, _options.ClientId, _options.ClientSecret);
        accessToken = await credential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext);
            
        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken.Token) || accessToken.ExpiresOn == default))
        {
            token = accessToken.Token;
        }
    }
    catch (RequestFailedException ex)
    {
    }                

    return token;
}

The client code is trying to access the resource https://lookupcityservice.dataserviceproviderxx.com.au.
The app service is registered to the domain dataserviceproviderxx.com.au in Azure Tenant.
When the new code is being called, it is throwing an exception on the credential.GetTokenAsync() line of code:

"The resource principal named https://lookupcityservice.dataserviceproviderxx.com.au was not found in the tenant named dataserviceproviderxx.com.au. This can happen if the application has...."

The Resource is registered in the tenant (which is working with the Old code). Is there anything we need to cinfigure.
Tried to search in Google but no happy result found.

Any update on the issue?

Initially I got the same error as below:


AADSTS500011: The resource principal named https://rukwebapptestxxxx.azurewebsites.net/ was not found in the tenant named Contoso. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

The error usually occurs if you are passing invalid scope or resource while generating the access token.
To resolve the error, check the below:
When you add the Identity provider as Microsoft and create a new application it will show the allowed audience value:

And in the Expose an API blade of the Microsoft Entra ID application a scope will be added, if not add the scope and expose an API:

Grant admin consent to the scope in API permissions blade:

Now to generate the access token pass scope api://ClientID/.default  like below:
I am able to successfully generate the access token like below:
using Azure;
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public class AzureAdOptions
    {
        public string Tenant { get; set; }
        public string ClientId { get; set; }
        public string ClientSecret { get; set; }
    }

    public class TokenService
    {
        private readonly AzureAdOptions _options;

        public TokenService(AzureAdOptions options)
        {
            _options = options;
        }

        public async Task<string> GetToken(string resourceURI)
        {
            var scope = resourceURI + "/.default";
            var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(new[] { scope });

            var token = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                var credential = new ClientSecretCredential(_options.Tenant, _options.ClientId, _options.ClientSecret);
                var accessToken = await credential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken.Token) && accessToken.ExpiresOn != default)
                {
                    token = accessToken.Token;
                }
            }
            catch (RequestFailedException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error getting token: {ex.Message}");
            }

            return token;
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var azureAdOptions = new AzureAdOptions
        {
            Tenant = "TenantID",
            ClientId = "ClientID",
            ClientSecret = "Secret"
        };

        var tokenService = new TokenService(azureAdOptions);
        string resourceURI = "api://ClientID";
        var tokenValue = tokenService.GetToken(resourceURI).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine($"AccessToken: {tokenValue}");
    }
}


Decoded token:

Using the above token, you can access the Azure Web App Service successfully.
Reference:
javascript - Error: AADSTS500011: The resource principal named "URL" was not found in the tenant - Stack Overflow by juunas
